# How to add line numbers to the lines of existing file

Tags: c, file

I need to add line numbers to each line of an existitng file.
My idea is to read `file1` add line number to each line ,store it in a separate variable and write in to `file2`.

Here are my code.

reading:

```
static char buff[100];
int lineNum = 0;
FILE *fp = fopen ("file1", "r");

    while (fgets (buff, sizeof (buff), fp) != NULL) {
    printf ("%7d: %s %s ", ++lineNum, buff);
   }
fclose (fp);
```

saving :

I need to store the results above in " str " so it can be written to file2

```
FILE *fp2 = fopen ("file2", "w");
fwrite(str , 1 , sizeof(str) , fp2 );
fclose(fp2);
```

Comment: 1. `printf ("%7d: %s %s ", ++lineNum, buff);` three params, two args. 2. `fwrite(str , 1 , sizeof(str) , fp2 );` Are we supposed to guess what str is? 3. No error checking on any `fopen()`

Comment: You can `fprintf` like `fprintf (fp2, "%7d: %s", ++lineNum, buff);`

Comment: Are you asking to "store the results" from the entire file1 in memory, and then write fo file2? Why not just keep both fp,fp2 opened simultaneously, and write one line at a time (plus line number) to fp2 immediately after it's read from fp? That is, rather than printf() after fgets(), just use an fprintf() to the already-opened fp2. And then fclose() them both after fgets() returns a NULL. Pretty much exactly what you're already doing.

Comment: @JohnForkosh Your suggestion sounds reasonable. You forgot to mention that this changes the behavior of application slightly (what may or may not be acceptable). With internal storage, you can read and write the file with _same_ name (i.e. output file may overwrite input file). Following your suggestion, this is not anymore possible (or wouldn't provide the expected results).

Comment: We need a [mcve].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please give a clear scenario, from whatever i could understand you could use the following sample code for your reference:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LINE    1024

int main()
{
    FILE    *inFile     = NULL,
            *outFile    = NULL;

    char    lCharBuff[MAX_LINE];

    int     lLineNum = 1;

    inFile  = fopen("main.c","r");
    outFile = fopen("out.txt","w"); 

    if(!inFile || !outFile)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file\n");
        return 0;
    }

    while(fgets(lCharBuff,MAX_LINE,inFile) != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(outFile,"%10d %s",lLineNum,lCharBuff);
        lLineNum++;
    }

    fclose(inFile);
    fclose(outFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do not spoonfed people who ask unclear questions - add a comment instead asking for `[mcve]` (expands to [mcve])

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thanks for suggestion, will keep in mind going forward